# Eclipse plugin to create an action when Eclipse is closed

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there an Eclipse extension point to create an action that is automatically called when Eclipse is closed?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an extension point but you can add a `IWorkbenchListener` listener to the workbench

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().addWorkbenchListener(listener);
```

The listener has two methods `preShutdown` called just before shutdown starts which can cancel the shutdown, and `postShutdown` called at the end of shutdown.